# Conditionally grab vehicle data depending on criteria specified as key-value pairs

Tags: java, object-oriented

Here is the case of ugly condition for the "if":

```
 private void setRequirementAttributes(List<CarParams> carParamsList) {
    Vehicle vehicle = this.getModel();
    for (CarParams item : carParamsList) {
        if(item.getInfo().getYear().equalsIgnoreCase(vehicle.getYear())
        && item.getInfo().getMark().equalsIgnoreCase(vehicle.getMark())
        && item.getInfo().getSeries().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(vehicle.getSeries().toSting)
        && item.getInfo().getSeries().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(vehicle.getSeries().toSting)
        || (item.getInfo().getCommInfo().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(vehicle.getCommInfo().toSting))){
             grabVehicleData();
        }
    }
}
```

so hard to read, but I need to add more details for "if condition". What is the way to refactor it, probably more elegant way for the condition.

Comment: What's `toSting`? This looks like pseudocode. Also, we can't give you good advice without seeing the supporting code.

Comment: @200_success, yes this is just an example to illustrate the idea. The main question is just refactor IF condition. Why do you need other code?

Comment: Because this is Code Review, we require real code, and we require context. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution can be to extract out local variables for each matching condition and use those to calculate the predicate that will actually be passed to the if statement. This way the variable names indicate what you want to match on

```
private void setRequirementAttributes(List<CarParams> carParamsList) {

    Vehicle vehicle = this.getModel();

    for (CarParams item : carParamsList) {

        boolean yearMatches = item.getInfo().getYear().equalsIgnoreCase(vehicle.getYear();
        boolean markMatches = item.getInfo().getMark().equalsIgnoreCase(vehicle.getMark());
        boolean seriesMatch = item.getInfo().getSeries().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(vehicle.getSeries().toSting());
        boolean commInfoMatches = item.getInfo().getCommInfo().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(vehicle.getCommInfo().toSting());

        boolean allChecksOut = yearMatches && markMatches && seriesMatch || commInfoMatches;

        if(allChecksOut){
             grabVehicleData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, definitely more readably than originally.